# Minimum Layover Time for International Arrivals at Fort Lauderdale Intl. Airport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, fll

My family and I are returning home from Lima, Peru arriving at Washington D.C. (DCA). We had booked JetBlue, with flight numbers B6 1824 and B6 1280. B6 1824 was originally supposed to depart LIM tonight, Friday August 11th at 11:55 PM, arriving at FLL at 6:50 AM; giving about 2 hrs and 30 min of layover for custom clearance (which is plenty). Now, B6 1824 got delayed by about 1 hour which leaves us with only 1 hr and 30 min for customs. Is this enough time for getting though customs at FLL? Just to add, we would need to take two checked bags out to go thru customs and then re-check in. We also have Global Entry AND TSA-Precheck. I am also worried that even if we make the flight, our bags wouldn't get to the plane in time. Some advice would be much appreciated!

I will also keep updated for those interested to know the result. Fingers crossed

Update: Unfortunately, JetBlue decided to close our hopes while delaying 30+ min. on the ground at Lima. Therefore, we missed our original connection with JetBlue and we are looking for other options.

Edit: For those who are familiar, do you know what compensation we can recieve IF we were to not make the connection and JetBlue proceeds to rebook us on a different flight?

Answer (score 1):

> We also have Global Entry AND TSA-Precheck.

That will help tremendously. You have a very good chance of making it.

> Just to add, we would need to take two checked bags out to go thru customs and then re-check in

That complicates matters a bit, but in most cases that should not be a problem. It rarely takes more than half an hour for bags to come out and it often is a lot faster.

> I am also worried that even if we make the flight, our bags wouldn't get to the plane in time.

That's generally not much of a problem since the airline will send them after you and deliver them to "wherever you are" when they finally show up. The tricky part here is the following: if the bags ARE running late, than you need to decide when to "abandon" them. At some point you have to give up waiting and walk out of customs without them. That time depends a bit on the details, i.e. what terminal and departure gate. I'd say 45 minutes is fine, 30 minutes is the absolute minimum. Boarding fore Jet Blue domestic closes 15 before departure. I would take a map and try to estimate how much the hike from international arrival to your departure gate would be adding at least 10 minutes for PreCheck security.

If JetBlue has an office (for lost baggage) in the claim area, I would go over there and ask right when you get to the baggage claim. Document all details around this in case Jet Blue will make a fuzz later.

> Edit: For those who are familiar, do you know what compensation we can recieve IF we were to not make the connection and JetBlue proceeds to rebook us on a different flight?

None. The USA has no compensation rules like the EU does. If may get a food voucher and maybe a hotel if you are stuck overnight but it's mostly the in the discretion of the airline.

> Some advice would be much appreciated!

Relax and enjoy the flight. You have an 80%+ chance of making this confection without a hitch.

Comment: It’s worth noting that the connection involves a terminal change in FLL (4 to 3). I’m not familiar with FLL at all so no idea what that entails.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, JetBlue decided to close our hopes while delaying 30+ min. on the ground at Lima. Currently at FLL waiting for checked bags. Guess we'll have to see what other flights JetBlue can get us on...

Comment: The US has no EU261-style compensation rules, but, unusually, [JetBlue does have rules of its own](https://www.jetblue.com/customer-assurance/cancellations-delays) which may apply here if the final arrival was delayed enough.